# Why does deepcopy fail with "KeyError: '__deepcopy__'" when copying custom object?

Tags: python, class, deep-copy

I have a class that converts a dictionary to an object like this

```
class Dict2obj(dict):
    __getattr__= dict.__getitem__

    def __init__(self, d):
        self.update(**dict((k, self.parse(v))
                           for k, v in d.iteritems()))

   @classmethod
   def parse(cls, v):
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        return cls(v)
    elif isinstance(v, list):
        return [cls.parse(i) for i in v]
    else:
        return v
```

When I try to make a deep copy of the object I get this error

```
import copy
my_object  = Dict2obj(json_data)
copy_object = copy.deepcopy(my_object)

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
copier = getattr(x, "__deepcopy__", None)
KeyError: '__deepcopy__'
```

But if I override the `__getattr__` function in the `Dict2obj` class I was able to do deep copy operation. See example below

```
class Dict2obj(dict):

    __getattr__= dict.__getitem__

    def __init__(self, d):
        self.update(**dict((k, self.parse(v))
                           for k, v in d.iteritems()))

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key in self:
            return self[key]
        raise AttributeError

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, v):
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            return cls(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            return [cls.parse(i) for i in v]
        else:
            return v
```

Why do I need to override `__getattr__` method in order to do a deepcopy of objects returned by this class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue occurs for your first class, because `copy.deepcopy` tries to call `getattr(x, "__deepcopy__", None)` . The significance of the third argument is that, if the attribute does not exist for the object, it returns the third argument.

This is given in [the documentation for `getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) -

> **`getattr(object, name[, default])`**
>
> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, getattr(x, 'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar. **If the named attribute does not exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise AttributeError is raised**.

This works as , if the underlying `__getattr__` raises `AttributeError` and the `default` argument was provided for the `getattr()` function call the `AttributeError` is caught by the `getattr()` function and it returns the default argument, otherwise it lets the `AttributeError` bubble up. Example -

```
>>> class C:
...     def __getattr__(self,k):
...             raise AttributeError('asd')
...
>>>
>>> c = C()
>>> getattr(c,'a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __getattr__
AttributeError: asd
>>> print(getattr(c,'a',None))
None
```

But in your case, since you directly assign `dict.__getitem__` to `__getattr__` , if the name is not found in the dictionary, it raises a `KeyError` , not an `AttributeError` and hence it does not get handled by `getattr()` and your `copy.deepcopy()` fails.

You should handle the `KeyError` in your `getattr` and then raise `AttributeError` instead. Example -

```
class Dict2obj(dict):

    def __init__(self, d):
        self.update(**dict((k, self.parse(v))
                           for k, v in d.iteritems()))

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return self[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(name)
    ...
```

Comment: what if we can't change the object class code? Is there an alternative simple way to simply make a copy of the object not tethered to the original?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to [Anand's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33388198/7705804) if you want to retain the `KeyError` with `__getattr__` instead of an `AttributeError` (i.e. if you want the same error being raised as for a normal dict), you can add

```py
__deepcopy__ = None
```

in your class definition.